# Can I generate a URI for an input stream

Tags: java, servlets, download, uri

There is data in Inputstream that has to be downloaded as an attachment. I am using servlets for this. Is it possible to create a URI for the input stream? so that, I can 'href' to that URI form the download button? If yes, how is it done? If no, any other ways in which this can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: Create a Servlet and write the content of the `InuptStream` to the response `OutputStream` and set appropriate headers for file download like `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"myFileName\"`